# jquery code doesnt seem to be working - MVC 3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

have added some jquery to a new MVC 3 project but the jquery code doesn't seem to be working.

the HTML and script is as follows:

```
<div class="LineItems">

        <div class="LineItemHeading">
            <span>ItemCode</span>
            <span>Description</span>
            <span>Qty</span>
            <span>UnitPrice</span>
            <span>Acc.Code</span>
            <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>

        <div class="LineItem">
            <input type="text" class="ItemCode" />
            <input type="text" class="ItemDescription" />
            <input type="text" class="ItemQty" />
            <input type="text" class="ItemPrice" />
            <input type="text" class="ItemAccCode" />
        </div>

        <button id="AddLineItem">Add Line Item</button>
        <button id="RemoveLineItem">Remove Line Item</button>
    </div>



<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#AddLineItem").click(function () {
        alert("function called.."); // the alert shows.
        $(".LineItem:last-child").clone().appendTo($(".LineItem"));
        $(".LineItem:last-child input").each(function () {
        $(this).val("");
        });
    });

</script>
```

Target is to copy the last row and append it to the end . (create a new row which is same as the last row.)

jquery seems to be added to the Master layout and the chrome developer tools doesnt seem to give any jquery error.

any help appreciated.

Comment: Remove the quotes from val() as you're setting the val() to nothing.

Comment: that is intended. when a line item div is copied, its values are set to blank. isn't this the correct method of doing this

Comment: What is thew desired outcome here? That inputs are added and then set to blank?

Comment: no input is added. that is the issue. :) . desires task is to create a new row . the approach i could think of is to clone the last row, set its values to blank and append to the div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not targeting the inputs with your selectors correctly. Try these changes - http://jsfiddle.net/aT8Bk/

```
$("#AddLineItem").click(function () {
    alert("function called.."); // the alert shows.
    $(".LineItem input:last-child").clone().appendTo($(".LineItem"));
    $(".LineItem input:last-child").each(function () {
        $(this).val("");
    });
});
```

Comment: but would this not only copy the last input field. i wish to clone the whole Last div and append it .

Comment: EDIT: See this update http://jsfiddle.net/aT8Bk/2/ You may want to modify your container divs to arrange this better.

Comment: thank you for the time and answer. the issue seemed to be a typo.


    $("#AddLineItem").click(function () {
        alert("function called..");
        $(".LineItem:last-child").clone().appendTo($(".LineItems"));
        $(".LineItem:last-child input").each(function () {
        $(this).val("");
        });
    });

Comment: I just made another update - http://jsfiddle.net/aT8Bk/3/ It properly clears the last set of inputs added.